# How to pass a greater than or less than sign through a parameter?

Tags: python

If it possible to pass a `>=` sign through a parameter: As in:

```
def example():
   num1 = 0
   num2 = 5
   sign1 = >=
   sign2 = <=

   test(num1, num2, sign1, sign2)

def test(num1, num2, sign1):
    while num1 sign1 0 and num2 sign2 5:
       print('whatever')
       num1+=1
       num2-=1
```

Obviously this isn't what I'm really trying to do; I was just wondering if it was possible...

Comment: Pass them as functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: No, operators are not objects in Python. Rather, use a function.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible using the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module. However they are treated as functions and not strings which is what they appear to be in your original attempt.

```
from operator import le, ge

def example():
   num1 = 0
   num2 = 5
   sign1 = ge
   sign2 = le


def test(num1, num2, sign1, sign2):
    while sign1(num1, 0) and sign2(num2, 5):
       print('whatever')
       num1+=1
       num2-=1
```